# "totals" explanation

Tags: order-totals

Can anyone explain the difference between

1. getBaseSubtotal
2. getSubtotal
3. getBaseGrandTotal
4. getGrandTotal
5. getSubtotalInclTax
6. getBaseSubtotalInclTax
7. getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount
8. getSubtotalWithDiscount

Maybe some "total" param has been missed. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All base methods return value for the total in store base currency, that is the cery default one. The other return value in order currency. If you have many currencies this eill be value of the currency the customer chose.